# How to make all copies of a shared_ptr equal to another shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I cannot figure this out.. Looks like I'm missing something simple?
What do I put in `MakePointToSameValue` so that at point `(1)`

- both b.ptr and c.ptr point to the same as a.ptr
- in other words, `a.ptr.get() == b.ptr.get() == c.ptr.get()`
- the value originally pointed to by b.ptr and c.ptr gets deleted

?

```
struct Test
{
public:
  Test( int val ) :
    ptr( std::make_shared< int >( val ) )
  {
  }

  void MakePointToSameValue( Test& other )
  {
    //what do I put here?
    //other.ptr = this->ptr; //doesn't do it
  }

private:
  std::shared_ptr< int > ptr;
};

Test a( 0 );
Test b( 5 );
Test c( b );

b.MakePointToSameValue( a );

//(1)
```

Copying the ptr does not work, since it does not alter c (well, c.ptr has it's refcount decreased by one). Note that I use `int` just for simplicty, but it should work for noncopyable types.

Why? I have a class representing values, any type of values, for use in a sort of compiler. The actual value, nor how it is stored, is known when it gets instantiated. The only thing known is the type. So the class stores a shared_ptr containing a placeholder for a value determined later on (corresponds to compiling the arguments of a function definition when passed as a pointer or reference: the compiler only knows type, nothing more). At runtime the placeholder should be replaced by an actual value.

**Edit** fresh start of the day, came up with this. I knew it was simple.

```
void MakePointToSameValue( Test& other )
{
  other.ptr.swap( ptr );
  ptr.reset();
  ptr = other.ptr;
}
```

Additional question now is: will the above work as expected for any standard compliant pointer?

Comment: Looks like you need two levels of indirection.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus see last paragraph

Comment: @BenVoigt I just tried what I think it is you mean and it's pretty simple and clean. If you post your comment accompanied with some pseudo-code I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two levels of indirection here.  While you're right that all `shared_ptr` objects point to a common metadata block that contains the count and the pointer to the actual value, if you tried to update that block to point to a different object, you'd now have two metadata blocks pointing to the same value, each with their own different idea of what the reference count is.  There's the right number (in the sense that it matches the reference count) of `shared_ptr` objects using each metadata block, so the count on each block will eventually reach zero, but there's no way to know which block is the last block to reach a count of zero (and hence should delete the value).  So `shared_ptr` sensibly doesn't allow changing the object pointer inside the metadata.  You can only associate the `shared_ptr` with a new metadata block, new count, new object.  And other pointers to the same object aren't affected.

The right way to do this is to use a second layer of indirection (`shared_ptr<shared_ptr<int> >`).  That way there's exactly one metadata block and exactly one count for each object.  Your update takes place to the intermediate shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I understand your requirements, `shared_ptr` does not contain any such mechanism; nor would any regular type. If you want this behaviour, you'll have to code it yourself. My suggestion: add a private static `std::list<std::weak_ptr<Test>> registry`; register each `Test` instance by adding it to the `registry` list in the constructor, and make sure to remove it in the destructor.

Then use that registry in `MakePointToSameValue` to iterate through all instances and reset the value of `ptr`.

If you're interested in efficiency and have a bit more instances than three, you'll want to replace the `list` with an `unordered_set`; and perhaps use `unique_ptr` rather than `shared_ptr` in your `Test` class.

Answer to additional question: no, it won't work. Look at the documentation of `reset()`: it resets one particular instance `shared_ptr`: it does nothing with (and knows nothing of) any other instances. When the reference count in the control block reaches zero, it additionally destroys the pointee, but that's it.

Comment: y u `std::list`? That's just silly. You can gain O(1) removal and addition with an `unordered_set`, for example.

Comment: Yep. Whether that's more efficient depends on the number of instances, which stijn didn't give us any lead on: if it's only three, my bet's still on the list. Otherwise, sure.

Comment: hmm, I thought this should be possible with shared_ptr? I mean, it contains everything needed (all copies have the same pointer/refcount object internally), I just cannot figure out how to put it to use atm.

Comment: This is not what `shared_ptr` is for, nor how it normally is implemented. Yes, there's a shared control block managed internally, a `shared_ptr` instance would typically have one pointer to the value, one pointer to the control block; the control block need have no back pointers to the `shared_ptr`instances. You might find some implementation with back pointers which allows you to hack around with the control block, but you'll be way outside standard C++.